# Toggle picture width

Tags: jquery, html, click, hide, show

I am trying to make a web page with some picture you can click on, which then expand. They also have to shrink after being clicked on a second time. I am pretty new to Jquery and the problem is that when I click on the image, it disappears.

**Here is the code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $(".imgclass").click(function(){    
    $(this).toggle(function()
       {$(this).animate({width: "400px"});},
        function()
       {$(this).animate({width: "120px"});
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this code if you're expecting the same. Just you need to `toggle` the class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $(".fotoklein").click(function(){    
    $(this).toggleClass('animate');
});
});
```

```css
.fotoklein{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#777;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  -transition-duration:0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
}
.animate{
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fotoklein">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the same style for different images change id="fotoklein" to class="fotoklein" .

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var small={width: "120px",height: "120px"};
        var large={width: "400px",height: "400px"};
        var count=1; 
        $("#fotoklein").css(small).on('click',function () { 
            $(this).animate((count==1)?large:small);
            count = 1-count;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="fotoklein" class="small" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/657703841085935616/EulXOwHD.png">
```

hope this will help you..

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding what the `toggle()` function does. [jQuery's toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) just shows and hides elements. You need something like this:

```
var big = false;

$(".imgclass").click(function(){    

    if (big) {
        $(this).animate({width: "120px"});
        big = false;
    } else {
        $(this).animate({width: "440px"});
        big = true;
    }

});
```

However, using a class like in Hitesh Misro's solution is even better.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var flag = false;

$('.foo').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('focus')) {
       $(this).animate({width: '-=2em'}, 300).removeClass('focus');
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        if(!flag) {
            $(this).animate({width: '+=2em'}, 300).addClass('focus');
            flag = true;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.foo{
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #456;
 height: 2em;
 margin: .5em;
 width: 4em;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">Click</div>
<div class="foo">Me</div>
```